# Math related Javascript for Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am having trouble figuring this math related problem out.

I am using the [jogDial.js](http://www.ohsean.net/plugins/jogdial/) plugin for a project.

With it, I'm trying to simulate a volume dial that controls the gainNode of the web audio api.

The plugin can return the degree of the dial with this:

```
console.log("event.target.degree: "+event.target.degree); 
//between +220 and +140
```

it can also return the rotation with this:

```
console.log("event.target.rotation: "+ event.target.rotation);
//between -140 and +140
```

I found the rotation easier to work with.

Simulating a real existing dial from a Harman/Karmon receiver, the lower limit is at a rotation of **-140**, the mid at **0**, and the upper limit at a rotation of **140**.

Here is an actual image of the dial so you have a visual representation (ignore the numbers 0 and 40 in the image):

[image]

My GainNode limits are **0** and **1**, with 1 being 100% volume, and 0 being silence.

At **-140 degrees**, that should be where the volume is at 0%. The web audio api gainNode.gain.value would be at **0**.

When the dial is at **0 degrees**, that would be the halfway point. Volume should be at 50%, or **0.50** value for the gainNode.gain.

When the dial is at **+140 degrees**, volume should be at 100%, or a gain value of **1** for the web audio api.

I'm having trouble figuring out a formula that will work within my **on("mousemove", function(event){});**

I tried this:

```
var volumeDial = JogDial(document.getElementById('volume-knob'), {
    debug: true,
    wheelSize: '90%',
    zIndex: '100',
    touchMode: 'wheel',
    knobSize: '3%',
    minDegree: -140,
    maxDegree: 140,
    degreeStartAt: 0
}).on("mousemove", function(event){
    var volume = event.target.rotation;
    console.log("event.target.rotation: "+ event.target.rotation);
    console.log("event.target.degree: "+event.target.degree);
    var theGain;
    theGain = Math.abs(50-(volume*0.3575)-100) *0.01;
    gainNode.gain.value = theGain;
console.log("gainNode.gain.value: "+gainNode.gain.value);
    source.connect(gainNode);
}).on("mouseup", function(event){
    console.log("event.target.rotation: "+event.target.rotation);
    console.log("event.target.degree: "+event.target.degree);
});
```

The problem is that it isn't accurate. Its close but not the desired effect. There is still sound at 0%, and from 0% to 100% there is not much difference audibly.

At 0%, I have a gain value of "0.0005000000237487257". The sound is nowhere near silent, its quite loud.

At 50% I have a gain value of 0.5, which is correct.

at 100% I have a gain value of 1.000499963760376.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really need is

```
(event.target.rotation + 140) / 280
```

I'm not even sure where you took that multiplier from.

Comment: That works... I also found a different issue with it altogether that was affecting it. I had to disconnect a previous source.connect from a different function that had its own set static gain level before this would work properly.

Comment: It's a bad idea to adjust the gain linearly with the position of the knob. When the gain is 0.5, it sounds almost as loud as 1.0, not half as loud. You really want an exponential function of the knob position, except that the gain should go all the way to zero when the knob is all the way down (an exponential function would never get quite to zero). Something like: `if (rotation == -140) gain = 0; else gain = Math.pow(10, (rotation - 140) / 200);` (you might want to try divisors other than 200 and see what sounds best, but that's the general idea).